# Rviz: How to set X, Y of TopDownOrtho View by code

Tags: ros

Is it possible to move the center of the **TopDownOrtho** view to coordinate (x, y) **by code**?
Although I can set (X, Y) in TopDownOrtho view by GUI.

Answer (score 0):

`lookAt(float x, float y, float z)` function in `rviz::ViewController` can do this.
TopDownOrtho view is a `rviz::FixedOrientationOrthoViewController` object, which is a derived class of `rviz::ViewController`.

And `rviz::ViewController` pointer can be got from `rviz::RenderPanel` pointer using `getViewController()` function.

`rviz::RenderPanel` pointer is the second parameter of `processKeyEvent()` function (`rviz::Tool`), and I used `lookAt()` in this function.